# Azure function Managed Identity properties

Tags: azure-functions

We have a Linux Python core Azure function with a system assigned managed identity.
We want to read files from an Azure blob storage via Azure function and do some file validations.
Is it possible to access the file from blob storage without the need of any Access key or SAS of blob storage with the concept of managed identity

Comment: Of course you can do this. If you use the SDK to operate, you should be able to see that the corresponding blob storage client construction has a construction method that takes credential as a parameter. You only need to pass in the credentials generated based on the MSI (in this case, the code will be verified against the MSI).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

SAS or Access key is just one authentication method.

Whether you use the REST API or the normal new version of the SDK, or you use any language, you should be able to use credential as a parameter to create a blob storage client. You only need to generate credentials based on the MSI (this should be imported directly from the verification package).